# How to create a callback priority queue with the help of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, queue, priority-queue

When doing `$(element).on('customevent',function(){});`, every element that binds the `customevent` will also trigger. This works roughly as a Pub/Sub, and it appears that there is no order or priority. What I want to do is, to implement my own callback queue, but, with ajustable priority (like what Wordpress has, you can set the hooks priorities). So a higher number have a bigger priority, and a number 0 will be a common and executed last.

Given the example `$(element).on_priority(10, 'customevent', function(){});` and `$(element).on_priority(0, 'customevent', function(){});`, the `10` priority will execute the same  `customevent` first, and might or not cancel the execution of the `0` priority event.

How can I implement that? I'm having trouble trying to visualize the flow of the callbacks

So far, I thought like this:

- Keep a "global" (inside my closure) object with all the callback names set.
- Inside each member of the callback, an object containing all the priorities.

```js
var callbacks = {
  'customevent': {},
  'customevent2': {
    0: [{element: $element, fn: function(), data:{}}, {element: $element, fn: function(), data:{}}],
   10: [{element: $element, fn: function(), data:{}}],
   20: [{element: $element, fn: function(), data:{}}]
  }
};
```

Is the right direction? Performance wise it shouldn't be much of a hit, the problem is iterating the object over and over. The problem with this is that I wouldn't be able to unregister a previously set event or set the order (or even reorder) the callback array inside each priority

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just suggest an array of callback objects that you could encapsulate in its own object.  The object has methods for add, remove and execute.  Add, adds a given callback in priority order.  Remove finds a callback and removes it.  Execute calls each callback in priority order, but stopping further execution of callbacks if any callback returns `false`.

Traversing the callbacks in priority order is simple (you just go from begin to end of the array) because the callbacks are kept in sorted order in the array.

```
function sortedCallbacks() {
    this.list = [];
}

sortedCallbacks.prototype = {
    // add callback to the list
    add: function(fn, priority, data) {
        var list = this.list;
        var callbackObj = {fn: fn, priority: priority, data: data};

        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            // if our new priority is greater, then insert it here
            if (priority > list[i].priority) {
                list.splice(i, 0, callbackObj);
                return;
            }
        }
        // if the list was either empty or no priorities in the list were less than
        // the new priority, then just add this onto the end of the list
        list.push(callbackObj);
    },
    // remove callback from the list
    remove: function(fn, priority) {
        var list = this.list;
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].fn === fn && list[i].priority === priority) {
                list.splice(i, 1);
                return;
            }
        }
    },
    // change priority or data or both
    change: function(fn, oldPriority, newPriority, data) {
        this.remove(fn, oldPriority);
        this.add(fn, newPriority, data);
    }
    // execute callbacks in order
    execute: function(/* args for callback passed here */) {
        // execute in priority order
        var list = this.list, retVal, args;
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
            // add the data for this callback to any arguments that were passed to execute
            args.unshift(list[i].data);
            retVal = list[i].fn.apply(this, args);
            // if callback returns false, then stop further callback execution
            if (retVal === false) {
                return;
            }
        }        
    }
};
```

Sample usage:

```
// create callbacks object and add some callbacks to it
var callbacks = new sortedCallbacks();
callbacks.add(fn1, 4, "whatever");
callbacks.add(fn2, 9, "hello");
callbacks.add(fn8, -1, "nothing");

// execute the callbacks and pass them each a value
callbacks.execute(elem.value)
```

Comment: that's an outstanding answer. I will try this and get back to this :)